# java - Inserting data into a database table where the value of the inputted data determines which table it will be stored

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

So yeah, i was wondering how to go around it. Like for example we a have a TextField, a Combobox and two database tables  (let's call them tbl_1 and tbl_2).
You can put anything in the TextField but the value of the ComboBox determines if the value in the TextField goes to tbl_1 or tbl_2. Any ideas?
Sorry, no code as I'm just musing.

Is the 'if' clause usable in this case like:

```
if (ComboboxValue == "some text from the dropdown menu"){ String sql = 
INSERT INTO tbl_1}
else{ String sql =  INSERT INTO tbl_2}
```

EDIT: I think I get the idea how to do this. Thanks guys for the comments.

Comment: search for strategy pattern

Comment: @Gnk I'll look into it.

Comment: I would separate my database logic. `if(comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("tbl_1 value")){
  DBHandler.runQuery(Object objectToStore);
 }
 else{DBHandler.runOtherQuery(Object objectToStore);}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals("tbl_1 value")) {
    String sql ="INSERT INTO tbl_1";
} else {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_2";
}
```

Comment: `sql` is not declared in the else block?

Comment: Yes, my mistake but the sql declaration doesn't matter in this post, i'm just showing him how to perform the condition to choose which table to put data into.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct an INSERT command based on your selection like this:

```
String Insert ＝ "INSERT INTO " ＋ (String)JComboBox.getSelectedItem() ＋ " VALUES " ＋ JTextField.getText()；
```

Comment: Looks interesting. Would care to elaborate?

Comment: I made a change in the code. Now I think it's more clear